# Mapbox: The list does not work when I try to change the lat/long of the geojson objects

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson

I tried out this code and it works perfectly, until I try to change the position of the markers. For example, in the geojson array, I changed the first variable's properties and when i click it on the list, it only shows the marker (no map). Could anyone see what the issue might be??

Here is the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/ohumVwCE0CqcZOIkzPTa?p=preview

```
var geojson = [{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        34.022591187904126, -118.28702688217165
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "phoneFormatted": "(213) 748-5116",
      "phone": "2022347336",
      "address": "1665 W Jefferson Blvd",
      "city": "Los Angeles",
      "country": "United States",
      "crossStreet": "at Jefferson",
      "postalCode": "90007",
      "state": "CA"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-77.049766,
        38.900772
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "phoneFormatted": "(202) 507-8357",
      "phone": "2025078357",
      "address": "2221 I St NW",
      "city": "Washington DC",
      "country": "United States",
      "crossStreet": "at 22nd St NW",
      "postalCode": "20037",
      "state": "D.C."
    }
```

As you can see, the first item on the list brings you to an unrecognized location. But the other items work just fine.

Comment: Very nice that the setActive method from my code works perfectly, it would be greatly appreciated if you would then take the time to accept the answer to your previous question. It's the least you can do if you want people to help you. And that way people who have the same problem can also find an accepted solution. It's what makes StackOverflow great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to this. Already accepted. Huge thanks by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have swapped your latitude and longitude:

```
"coordinates": [
    34.022591187904126, -118.28702688217165
]
```

That's invalid, the latitude now exceeds the boundaries of -90/90 and the map doesn't know what to do with that. If you swap them, it works perfectly:

```
"coordinates": [
    -118.28702688217165, 34.022591187904126
]
```

Comment: No problem, we've all made that mistake at one point or another :) When you're lucky and the coordinates are valid (within the boundaries), you could at least see on the map that you've got the wrong coordinates. Wasn't in this case, hence the confusion. Good luck with your map!